# How do you write in a text box in the Game Engine within Blender?

Tags: text-object

So when I was going to make a little game, I wanted the game's name, then created by Cool Guy (that's me!) underneath it, so I created a text box and tried to write in it, but it would not work. How do I write in the text box?

Comment: What do you mean "`I created a text box`"? How did you try to write on it, and why didn't it work? Please edit your question and provide more information

Answer (score 1):

If it is a text object, you can <kbd>Tab</kbd> into edit mode and change the text value ahead of time. If you want to edit it *realtime* in you game please see the following steps:

### Step 1

Switch your screen layout to **"Game Logic"** or open a Logic Editor window.

[image]

Now add the text object and position it where you want it.

### Step 2

Under the logic properties for the Text object, click the special button that says "Add Text Game Property". A new string property called "Text" will appear, but alas! you cannot edit it directly. You need some game logic. Add a normal game property, set it to boolean, and give it a name you will remember. Now create a new Keyboard sensor, enable "All Keys" mode, and under the *log toggle* field, select your boolean property. Lastly, under the *target* field, select your property "Text".

[image]

### Step 3

Profit. You now have a system where you can dynamically change a text objects lettering *in game*, but it will only happen when you enable the boolean property. i.e. if in a first person shooter, you could set it to toggle when keypress[right enter key] so you don get long string of "WWWASASAAWWWWWWWWWDD".

Hope this works for you. Happy blending.